# change *.msf file into excel file

Tags: sqlite

I have a *.msf file.

How I can convert/export my protein *.msf file to an excel or txt file?

Thanks in advance for great help!

Best,

Yue

```
$ sqlite3
SQLite version 3.22.0 2018-01-22 18:45:57
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
sqlite> .open LD-CS-150113_OstromR_OR_AC2_enriched.msf
sqlite> .table
AminoAcidModifications                PeptidesProteins_decoy              
AminoAcidModificationsAminoAcids      PeptidesReferenceSpectra            
AminoAcidModificationsAminoAcidsNL    PeptidesTerminalModifications       
AminoAcidModificationsNeutralLosses   PeptidesTerminalModifications_decoy 
AminoAcids                            Peptides_decoy                      
AnnotationDataVersion                 PrecursorIonAreaSearchSpectra       
AnnotationDataset                     PrecursorIonQuanResults             
AnnotationGroups                      PrecursorIonQuanResultsSearchSpectra
AnnotationTypes                       ProcessingNodeConnectionPoints      
Annotations                           ProcessingNodeExtensions            
AnnotationsAnnotationGroups           ProcessingNodeFilterParameters
```

Comment: What I understand from https://www.biostars.org/p/411703/ is that an MSF file contains a sqlite database. You'll need to query that to be able to export to Excel or TXT

Comment: Please read the tag info wiki for the tag you used ( https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sqlite/info ) and provide a MRE as described there for a suitably small tailored sample database of your importing. Then show the desired output for that. It is not clear what kind of table structure in the excel file you want to represent the data in the listed tables.